# C programming 2D arrays. Why the int j in this program always default to zero even though its an auto variable?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int arr[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int j;
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        printf("%d",arr[i+1][j+1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output - 580
Does the output depends on the compiler?
why the auto variable j defaults to 0?
what happens if j contains a garbage value if it doesn't default to zero? What will be the output then?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. An unitialized auto variable may contain any value. If it contains 0 is because of the way your compiler implemented it, or the way your SO initializes memory for your stack/program/data area

Comment: @hnefatl In C "auto" means "automatic storage", not "automatic type inferred". auto in fact is a reserved word in C, even it's rarely used.

Comment: First thing that you might get a SEG fault because you are trying to access arr[3][j + 1]. It depends on the compiler but if it's a garbage value you might be left with SEG fault

Comment: @Sai:  There is no "should" get a seg-fault.  The program *might* seg-fault, or might run producing garbage output.   Seg-fault is not required and not guaranteed.  In general, you'll find you can go a little-bit past most arrays without an error, just getting unpredictable values.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that `j` is not initialized, and therefore might have ***any*** value in it.   It apparently happens to have `0` in your test run, but that is not guaranteed at all.

If `j` has some other non-zero "garbage" value, the output could be anything at all, including a program crash.